# SQL Multiple select from three tables with foreign keys

Tags: sql, database

I need to select from table application (left) and table services (right) the name of the values in the middle table. Since the middle table contains all foreign keys of the table application and services. I know I'm supposed to use join or something. HELP!

[image: http://s1078.photobucket.com/user/Stephanie_Faith_Feliciano/media/ben_zps0a55e33c.png.html]

**Table definitions:**

Table 1: Application

```
Column 1: int ApplicationID (PK)
Column 2: nvarchar(255) Name
```

Table 2: Service

```
Column 1: int ServiceID (PK)
Column 2: nvarchar(255) Name
```

Mapping table: ApplicationToService

```
Column 1: int ApplicationToServiceID (PK)
Column 2: int ApplicationID (FK)
Column 3: int ServiceID (FK)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you just want a list that combines all applications with their services?

Comment: Please provide full table definition, based on what is in a picture you can't do what you want as App Table has no ID nor does the Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will indeed require a JOIN command.

In the following example I use the INNER JOIN command as it's the most commonly used (at least for me), but you may replace with another join if you prefer.

Here is a diagram of the different types of joins at your disposal:
[image: Print me out and hang me up]

Based on the assumption that your tables are:

Table 1: **Application**

- Column 1: int **ApplicationID** (PK)
- Column 2: nvarchar(255) **Name**

Table 2: **Service**

- Column 1: int **ServiceID** (PK)
- Column 2: nvarchar(255) **Name**

Mapping table: **ApplicationToService**

- Column 1: int **ApplicationToServiceID** (PK)
- Column 2: int **ApplicationID** (FK)
- Column 3: int **ServiceID** (FK)

Example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    ApplicationToService
    INNER JOIN Application ON ApplicationToService.ApplicationID = Application.ApplicationID
    INNER JOIN Service ON ApplicationToService.ServiceID = Service.ServiceID
```

You may replace the * with individual fields, but since you are now dealing with multiple tables, you must precede each column name with the table name like so:

```
SELECT
    ApplicationToService.ApplicationToServiceID
    , Application.Name
    , Service.Name
FROM 
    ApplicationToService
    INNER JOIN Application ON ApplicationToService.ApplicationID = Application.ApplicationID
    INNER JOIN Service ON ApplicationToService.ServiceID = Service.ServiceID
```

Your table and column names may be less verbose than mine, but I find it good practice to keep them descriptive.

If you need this explaining further then don't be afraid to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from appmaster a
inner join appservmap asm on a.appid=asm.appid
inner join servicemaster s on asm.servid=s.servid
```