# Trying to join tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new to MySQL and PHP. And i have some problems trying to get data values from two tables in one query using JOIN. What i want to do is query "user_builds" and SUM(amount) where the owner_id=1 AND type=1. The problems comes in now where i have to grab the build_type from another table called "builds".

I have tried to solve this as i mentioned with JOIN, but the closest i came was to get the amount of rows that was equal to how many rows user_id=1 had.
What i want is select the total SUM of "amount"(user_builds) where "type=1"(builds) and "owner_id=1"(user_builds).

I hope you understand what i try to do here, if not i will try to elaborate it more. And also sorry for not providing any of the querys i tried, but as none of them worked it feels irrelevant. Thank you for your time.

Edit:

```
+-------------------+
| user_builds       |
+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| id      |owner_id | build_id | amount|
+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| 1       |    1    |    1     |   5   |
| 2       |    2    |    2     |  15   |
| 3       |    2    |    3     |  15   |
| 4       |    1    |    4     |   5   |
| 5       |    1    |    5     |   5   |
| 6       |    1    |    6     |  10   |
+---------+---------+----------+-------+

+----------------------+
| build                |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------+
| id      | name       |description| type   |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------+
|    1    | House      | desc      |    1   |
|    2    | Kitchen    | desc      |    2   |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------+
```

I want to query "user_builds" and get the total of "amount" where owner_id=1 and type=1. (type is found in "build" table).

Comment: Can you please share your tables' structure, some sample data, and the result you expect to get for this sample data?

Comment: your explanation is very dull can you please show your  data and requirement .That will be easy to understand.

Comment: Easiest for all here would be if you prepare a sqlfiddle with your tables and some test data.

Comment: which one is your main table ..???

Comment: and what are the common field to join on which table ..??

Comment: which two are related fields in two table ..???
to join any query there is to be common field in both table ..

Comment: build_id gets it's value from the table "build" - > id(primary, AI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, I hope it works appropriately.

```
select sum(ub.amount)
  from user_builds ub
  left join build b 
    on ub.build_id = b.id
 where b.type=1 
   and ub.owner_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That's what i was after! :) Sadly ppl downvoted me so i cant give you rep now.. I appreciate your help tho!

Comment: No problem, you can learn about joins from [w3schools sql joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and this [infographic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23653569/4879022)

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(amount) from user_builds left join builds on build.type = user_builds.type where "owner_id=1"
```

try this query and replace my query field with your original fields

best of luck...