# MySQL Selecting all records from one table and their matches/NULL from another table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. Two of them are separate irrelevant tables (students and subjects), the third (entries) is one which links them both with foreign keys (student_id and subject_id).

Here are all the tables with the records:

students:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| student_id | first_name | surname   | email               | reg_date            |  
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 | Emily      | Jackson   | emilym@gmail.com    | 2012-10-14 11:14:13 |
|          2 | Daniel     | ALexander | daniela@hotmail.com | 2014-08-19 08:08:23 |
|          3 | Sarah      | Bell      | sbell@gmail.com     | 1998-07-04 13:16:32 |
|          4 | Alex       | Harte     | AHarte@hotmail.com  | 1982-06-14 00:00:00 |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

subjects:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
| subject_id | subject_name | exam_board | level_of_entry |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
|          1 | Art          | CCEA       | AS             |
|          2 | Biology      | CCEA       | A              |
|          3 | Computing    | OCR        | GCSE           |
|          4 | French       | CCEA       | GCSE           |
|          5 | Maths        | OCR        | AS             |
|          6 | Chemistry    | CCEA       | GCSE           |
|          7 | Physics      | OCR        | AS             |
|          8 | RS           | CCEA       | GCSE           |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

entries:

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
| entry_id | student_id_fk | subject_id_fk | entry_date |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
|        1 |             1 |             1 | 2012-10-15 |
|        2 |             1 |             4 | 2011-09-21 |
|        3 |             1 |             3 | 2015-08-10 |
|        4 |             2 |             6 | 1992-07-13 |
|        5 |             3 |             7 | 2013-02-12 |
|        6 |             3 |             8 | 2016-01-14 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

How would I go about selecting the names of all the students (students.first_name), and the name (subjects.subject_name) of whichever subject entries they have? What I mean is that all student names are returned, and all the subject names for their entries listed beside them, with NULL for those which don't have any entries. I also want it grouped by the first_name alphabetically.

I want the output to be something like:

```
first_name    subject_name
--------------------------
Alex          NULL
Daniel        Chemistry
Emily         French
Emily         Computing
Sarah         Physics
Sarah         RS
```

though I'm not sure if that's entirely correct.

My guess is it's like this:

```
SELECT students.first_name, subjects.subject_name
FROM students
JOIN entries ON entries.student_id_fk = students.student_id
JOIN subjects ON entries.subject_id_fk = subjects.subject_id
GROUP BY  students.first_name;
```

Really the only thing I'm not sure about is which join to use and where to put it, or if the tables need to be listed in a different order. I'm thinking it should be a left join but I'm not sure.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` should work. Isn't it working with left join?

Comment: You can learn about joins from [w3schools sql joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and this [infographic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23653569/4879022)

Comment: One question, from your example you only have `NULL` in the `subject_name` column for your results, the answer I provided below assumes you you do not want `NULL` matches in the `students` side of the query. That you want all students regardless of matching subjects. If that is incorrect and you also want all subjects that may not have any student matches, then scaisEdge's answer takes care of that. My query will not have any nulls in the students list, only in the subjects. That means you will get all students, but if there is no student for a subject that subject will not appear in the list.

Comment: You are right in thinking I don't want any null values in the students list. Thanks

Comment: Then you would want my answer instead. Mine results in no nulls in the student list, only in the subjects.

Comment: @Dovahkiin Check the infograpghic mentioned in my comment above, it helps to judge which join to choose when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use left join since you want to return also row for student that has no subject assigned. Plus you want to sort the result, not group. So in the end should be like this:

```
SELECT students.first_name, subjects.subject_name
FROM students
LEFT JOIN entries ON entries.student_id_fk = students.student_id
LEFT JOIN subjects ON entries.subject_id_fk = subjects.subject_id
ORDER BY  students.first_name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you perhaps explain to me why left join is used both times and not just the first one?

Comment: After first join on entries table you get conjunction of students and entries tables (Each row will have columns from both tables). If you would use just JOIN, you will not have rows for students that are not present in entries table (Alex). With LEFT JOIN, you will also have Alex and all the columns for entries table will be null in this row. Second join will connect this data with subjects table. If you would use just JOIN, you would lose Alex row, because it cannot be joined tiwh subjects table (entries.subject_id_fk column is NULL, so this row would be dropped). Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the query but use order by and not group by (group by is for aggregate function like count() or max() )

```
SELECT students.first_name, subjects.subject_name
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN students ON entries.student_id_fk = students.student_id
LEFT JOIN subjects ON entries.subject_id_fk = subjects.subject_id
ORDER  BY  students.first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
select stu.first_name, sub.subject_name
from students stu
join entries e
on stu.student_id = e.student_id_fk
left outer join subjects sub
on sub.subject_id = e.subject_id_fk
order by stu.first_name;
```

I'm away from my PC with any SQL installed, so this is untested, but should give you what you want.

- Modified my answer to replace the `group by` with an `order by` as pointed out by the others. That is the proper way to do it, unless the group is there as part of a larger query that you may have trimmed out.

Answer (score 0):

**Left join** students table on the remaining two tables sequentially is the right choice to grab all the students first name.

To order the names **order by** should be used.

I have create a sql fiddle for better visualization of how to get the desired output.

Here is the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1c850/7

The query is

```
select students.student_name, subjects.subject_name
from 
students
left join entries on entries.student_id=students.student_id
left join subjects on entries.subject_id=subjects.subject_id
order by students.student_name;
```